# Execute JavaScript using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, vba

Hi I am trying to execute a JavaScript in VBA in the native excel application using Selenium Wrapper.

The following code executes a JavaScript on Chrome Console and gives me my expected output.

```
$x("//label[text()[contains(.,'British')]]")[0].children[1].children[0].click()
```

To execute JavaScript usually it needs to be in double quotes however this is not accepted by VBA since it has two double quotes.

```
driver.ExecuteScript("$x("//label[text()[contains(.,'British')]]")[0].children[1].children[0].click()")
```

I tried to define it as a string in another variable with the concatenation of the values, but it is still giving me error.

I don't want findElementByXpath with click method. Would request if anyone knows a workaround of this.

**Edit 1**
instead of $x which works on chrome, using document.evaluate works in webdriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth,

```
driver.ExecuteScript("$x("//label[text()[contains(.,'British')]]")[0].children[1].children[0].click()")
```

should be written like this:

```
driver.ExecuteScript("$x(""//label[text()[contains(.,'British')]]"")[0].children[1].children[0].click()")
```

Comment: Since you cannot click an element which is not displayed using webdriver, but executing a javascript works even if the element is not displayed.