# Excel VBA - How do I move by a drop-down menu with Selenium (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, selenium

I have to access through Excel VBA to a **web that is only compatible with Chrome or Firefox (not IE)**. I have managed to access the web using Selenium but I can not move through the drop-down menu to get to the section in which I must upload the data.

The menu link that I have to click is the following one:
[drop-down menu element's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBTOi.png)

I have tried with FindElementByLinkText but it is not working, I suppose that I have to call some JavaScript function (on_load_form?) but I do not know how to do that. Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Executor in Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44289599/execute-javascript-using-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED with this code:
bot.ExecuteScript ("on_load_form('v_aux_presupuesto.php','',false,false,false,false,'app');")